# if statement in function is not executing

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I have created a database with RSQLite, the connection=`conn`. In this Database is a Datatable `dummy` with `key`and `text`.

```
conn <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "~/path.db")

dbExecute(conn,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'dummy' (
          key CHAR(27) PRIMARY KEY,
          text TEXT)")
```

And I have created a function `dummy_func`. My problem is, that the conditions with `if (! is.null(conn))` are not executed, when i call the function with `dummy_func("key1")`. But if i type `! is.null(conn)` in the console i'm getting a `TRUE`. So, the conditon should work, correct?

```
key <- as.character("key1")

dummy_func <- function(key, conn=NULL)
{
  if (! is.null(conn))  {
    qry <-
      dbSendQuery(conn,
                  "SELECT key FROM dummy WHERE key=key1")
    dbBind(qry, key)
    output <- dbFetch(qry)
  }

  if (! identical(output$key, character(0))) {
    ...
  } else {
 
      if (! is.null(conn))  {
        qry2 <-
          dbSendQuery(
            conn,
            "INSERT INTO dummy (key,text) VALUES(?,?)"
          )
      }
    }
  }
}
dummy_func("key1")
```

This is the error message where you can see, that the `output` was not created.

```
Error in identical(output$key, character(0)) : object 'output' not found
```

Comment: It seems you assign `conn=NULL` by default in function. Did you try calling `dummy_func("key1",conn)` ?

Comment: If I'm calling this, I'm getting no error message, but the result is the same (no `output`). If I'm execute just the if statement `if (! is.null(conn))` in the function, then it works fine (`output` are creating).

Comment: Because you forgot to add `return(output)`.  Or if you want to use the  "output" in the global environment without returning anything, you should use double arrow like  `output <<- dbFetch(qry)`.

Comment: Yeah now its works! I didn't know about the double arrow. Thank you.